# ¿cómo puedo darle color a un texto en la consola?

Tags: c++, consola

Necesito mostrar un vector que se vaya ordenando y, cada vez que haga un intercambio, los valores que están en posición correcta se muestren de un color y los demás en otro.

```
int main(){int v[]={3,5,4,2,1};// vector desordenado
int aux, izq, der, m, j;

for(int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
    aux = v[i];
    izq = 0;
    der =i-1;

    while(izq <= der) {
        m = (izq+der)/2;
        if(aux <= v[m]){
            der = m -1;
        }else
            izq = m+1;       
    }
    j = i-1;
    while(j>= izq) {
        v[j+1] = v[j];
        cout<<endl;
        mostrar(v,6);
        j = j-1;
    }
    v[izq]= aux;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Lo que necesito es que me muestre el vector desordenado en un color y al momento de hacer un cambio de posición los valores que estén ordenados dentro del vector se muestren en otro color.

Comment: podrias agregar el codigo de lo que tienes hasta ahora? si no la pregunta sera marcada como de baja calidad!

Comment: El estándar no dispone de ninguna utilidad para darle color al texto. Puedes usar librerías de terceros, como ncurses, o mirarte la API del sistema operativo que estés usando.